# Visual Studio Code - Node.js debugger "Breakpoint set but not yet bound"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a plain node.js application in Visual Studio Code *[Version: 1.44.2 / Node.js: 12.8.1]*, but my breakpoints are grayed out and show a hint "Breakpoint set but not yet bound".

I have tried a lot of suggested settings for launch.json, including launching the application into the terminal and attaching to it, but i could not make the breakpoints to be hit.

Any fresh ideas?

EDIT: Sample code you can try with

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    console.log('test ' + i);
    i++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: how about put your code to jsfiddle or somewhere that we can test

Comment: Can you show the .json file?

Comment: Any sample node.js code will do the job. I"ll post a basic example in a while.